# Why the sample method of mixture distribution works?

Tags: sample, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

For example this thread: [Generating random variables from a mixture of Normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70855/generating-random-variables-from-a-mixture-of-normal-distributions)

1. First choose a distribution according to the weights.
2. Then sample from the chosen distribution.

How to prove the correctness of this method?

Comment: Consider the cdf of the result.

Comment: @Glen_b How to formulize the proving goal? Cound you give some key steps?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures ... show the procedure is either the cdf of a mixture or the pdf of a mixture by establishing that you get what's on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I think about it.

Let 
\begin{equation}
p(y,z) = p(y|z)\,p(z) , 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
p(y|z) = \textsf{N}(y|\mu_z,\sigma_z^2)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
p(z = c) = \begin{cases}
w_c & c \in \{1, \ldots, K\} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and $w_c \ge 0$ and $\sum_{c=1}^K w_c = 1$. We can make a draw from the joint distribution by first drawing $z$ from its marginal distribution and then drawing $y$ from its conditional distribution.

The marginal distribution for $y$ is given by integrating out $z$. Because $z$ is discrete, this amounts to 
\begin{equation}
p(y) = \sum_{c=1}^K p(y|z)\,p(z=c) = \sum_{c=1}^K w_c\,\textsf{N}(y|\mu_c,\sigma_c^2) . 
\end{equation}
Thus, the marginal distribution for $y$ is a mixture. We may draw from this marginal distribution by drawing $z$ and $y$ from the joint distribution and discarding $z$.

Comment: Why $p(y)=p(y|z=c)p(z=c)$ doesn't hold considering the sample is only from the $z=c$ distribution? I think you only use the Law of total probability.