# Generating a simulated dataset from a mixture of two-trait Gaussian distributions

Tags: r, simulation, gaussian-mixture-distribution

How can I generate a random variable which follows the mixture Gaussian distributions:
[image]

I found the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70855/generating-random-variables-from-a-mixture-of-normal-distributions) and tried to simulate it, but I think it is not the right dataset
I wanted.

Here is my code:

```
M = 100
sigma1 = matrix(c(0.2, 0, 0, 0),ncol=2)
sigma2 = matrix(c(0, 0, 0, 0.4),ncol=2)
sigma12 = matrix(c(0.2, 0.028, 0.028, 0.4),ncol=2)
U = runif(M)
b = cbind(rep(NA,M),rep(NA,M))
for (i in 1:M) {
  if (U[i]<.8) {
    b[i,] = c(0,0)
  } else if (U[i]<.85) {
    b[i,] = rmvnorm(1,sigma = sigma1)
  } else if (U[i]<.9) {
    b[i,] = rmvnorm(1,sigma = sigma2)
  } else {
    b[i,] = rmvnorm(1,sigma = sigma12)
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you assume it's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want a Gaussian with zero variance? Also, you use undefined variables in the code (genMat1, ...)

Comment: @frank, sorry, I've fixed the typo in the code (sigma1 instead of genMat1). And yes, I want a Gaussian with zero variance.

Comment: There is no Gaussian with zero variance. You probably want a singular probability mass at zero?

Comment: The simulated data looks good to me. So, I would repeat @Tim's question: why do you assume it is wrong?

Comment: I plot the true density as a sanity check shown in the answer([link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70855/generating-random-variables-from-a-mixture-of-normal-distributions))
`x = seq(-20,20,.1)
      truth = .8*cbind(rep(0,nrow(x)),rep(0,nrow(x)))+.05*dmvnorm(x,sigma = 
      sigma1) + .05*dmvnorm(x,sigma = sigma1) + .1*dmvnorm(x,sigma =sigma12)
      plot(density(d),main="Density Estimate of the Mixture Model",ylim=c(0,.2),lwd=2)
      lines(x,truth,col="red",lwd=2)`
The truth density plot is different from b density.